# Unity Transform position isn't changing position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to change the position of a border to be just off the top of the screen. I did this by taking the top of the screen, then adding half the scale of the object (since it is centered in the middle). However, when I do this nothing changes at all. I printed out the coordinates and it says it moved, but it didn't. Here is my code (from the Start() method in WallScalar class).

***Note:*** The following code is the only code in the WallScalar class, this script is applied to the "Top" gameObject.

```
      transform.position = 
      new Vector3(0, Camera.main.orthographicSize + (transform.localScale.y / 2), 1);

      print("yCoor: " + transform.position.y);
```

Since the object has a scale of one, and the top is at y = 5, the object should be placed at y = 5.5f. With that print statement, it says it is at y = 5.5f but it didn't move on my screen. Here is an image for more details:

[image]

As you can see, it says it was moved to yCoor = 5.5f, but it didnt, because when I manually type 5.5 for y, it isn't visible, it is just off the screen. 
Any help with figuring this out would be greatly appreciated.

Update: If i put a print statement such as

```
      print("yCoorU: " + transform.position.y);
```

In my update method, it reads y = 5, so something is forcing it back to be 5, but know that nothing else has any call to the "Top" GameObject that the script is being applied to.

Comment: what does the wall scalar script do ? Perhaps its moving your wall back to 5?

Comment: @UriPopov I will edit and clarify, that is where the code you see above lives.

Comment: what is the size of your orthographic camera ?

Comment: another question.Is walls the parent object of Top at 0,0,0 ?

Comment: @UriPopov it is, and it is of size 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are dividing by an int, I think that the result of `transform.localScale.y / 2` might be 0 instead of 0.5 (although I don't undestand why your print would give the right value)

Comment: **Camera.main.orthographicSize**`+ (transform.localScale.y / 2)`. You forgot the `+Camera.main.orthographicSize` part. so getting float is not a surprise here.

Comment: I don't think that it makes a difference. the part in parenthesis might be cast to int

Comment: I read your answer wrong. My comment is a reply to **I don't understand why your print would give the right value**. I thought you said **I don't understand why your print would give a float value**. I read it again and realized it's a different stuff...

Answer (score 3):

So, what I figured out is that you have to disable the object you are trying to change position on, set the position and than enable it.

```
Player.SetActive(false);
Player.transform.position = new Vector3(PositionX, PositionY, PositionZ);
Player.SetActive(true);
```

This might be because during gameplay the player or the object you are trying to move is in static mode.

Chirag Shah

Answer (score 0):

I managed to replicate your problem by having a 0.5 value of the Y of the parent object. Make sure your parent object is at 0,0,0

Comment: It is, I double checked

Comment: only other thing I can think of is that the scale of the parent might be affecting it.